# The output of Model from Decision Tree and Random Forests are different?

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, decision-trees

I have been made a model using both Decision Tree and Random Forest. But, when I tried to test the model on the same DataFrame the output is different. How is this possible?

The [data file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bhaskoro-muthohar/DataScienceLearning/master/HR_comma_sep.csv) from my repo:

```
#This is the function to help me preparing the dataframe
def process_df_for_ml(df):
    """
    Process a dataframe for model training/prediction use.

    Returns X/y tensors.
    """

    df = df.copy()
    # Map salary to 0,1,2
    df.salary = df.salary.map({"low": 0, "medium": 1, "high": 2})
    # dropping left and sales X for the df, y for the left
    X = df.drop(["left", "sales"], axis=1)
    y = df["left"]
    return (X, y)
```

I used the decision tree:

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Train a decision tree.
X, y = process_df_for_ml(df)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, stratify=y)
clftree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3)
clftree.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

With test_score: 0.96. Afterwards, I test this DecisionTree to the same df and the output I got is [424 rows x 11 columns]

and then I tried to use Random Forest algorithm

```
X, y = process_df_for_ml(df)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# implementing train-test-split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=0, stratify=y)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
# random forest model creation
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
rfc.fit(X_train,y_train)
# predictions
rfc_predict = rfc.predict(X_test)
```

With test_score: 0.99. Afterwards, I test this RandomForest to the same df and the output I got is [11 rows x 11 columns].

How is this possible?
Here is the link to my works:
[DecisionTree](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hGNgcOjRjBhWG-OQmaZkhNvrT3e7RgN2) and [RandomForest](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ePADHUWvLdB6ivfg0wW9Cr5HU0m80eeR)

Comment: Even though the ideas in both models are similar, at the end of the day they are different models, no reason for them to give same the same result.

Comment: @serali which models are usually superior, is it models from decision tree or random forest? And in this case which models should I believe?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to say which is superior without experimentation. Here is  another post discussing pros and cons of each model in detail: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285834/difference-between-random-forests-and-decision-tree

Comment: @serali so basically, my works are already right but the different given results need more study to answer the why it's different?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "the output I got is <shape>"; what output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Data Preparation

By default, `train_test_split` will assume your train:test split to be 75:25 if you don't declare otherwise for either the `test_size` or `train_size` parameters. [See here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

For your decision tree, you don't declare this and so you test on 25% of the data, whereas you explicitly state in your data preparation for the random forest algorithm that the train size should be 33%.

Correcting for this ensures a fair comparison of the two algorithms in this scenario. I have assumed you wish to use `test_size=0.33`.

### 2. Model Differences

The random forest classifier is an ensemble method. As its name implies, this method generates a 'forest' of many decision tree classifiers that each train on a different subset of samples and features from the training data. The `n_estimators`, `max_samples` and `max_features` parameters control this. [See here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html). The results of each tree are then averaged with the aim of providing a more robust estimator.

In order for the two classifiers to produce the same output, I can set the same `random_state` and `max_depth` whilst allowing all features to be used (since by default all samples are used in every tree generated) in the random forest:

```
tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0, max_depth=3)
ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0, max_depth=3, max_features=None)
```

Both now achieve an identical test accuracy of 0.9551 because both classifiers generate the same identical tree.

Removing `max_features=None` allows the random forest classifier to randomly select features for each subset trained upon by each respective tree in the random forest:

```
ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0, max_depth=3)
```

Resultantly, the random forest classifier now achieves a test accuracy of 0.9121.

Hopefully, this explains why you were getting different results for the decision tree and random forest classifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Your df row count is 14,999

Your test data is 33% ~ 4950

So, your y_predict should be (4950,1) i.e. a binary prediction for all test rows.

This is what I am getting when running your code which you have posted here.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bhaskoro-muthohar/DataScienceLearning/master/HR_comma_sep.csv')

print(df.size)
# Map salary to 0,1,2
df.salary = df.salary.map({"low": 0, "medium": 1, "high": 2})
# dropping left and sales X for the df, y for the left
X = df.drop(["left", "sales"], axis=1)
y = df["left"]

#splitting the train and test sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=0, stratify=y)
# Train a decision tree.
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clftree = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3)
clftree.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clftree.predict(X_test) 
print(y_pred.size)
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
# random forest model creation
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
rfc.fit(X_train,y_train)
# predictions
rfc_predict = rfc.predict(X_test)
print(rfc_predict.size)
```